# sql join takes a long time to load

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello fellow programmers. I have an issue with load times when using a join in my SQL query. The two tables that are being joined have roughly 5000 rows each. Any way I can cut the load time on this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

`SELECT applications.appId, applications.clientId, applications.applicationDate, applications.approved, client.cryptId, client.firstName, client.lastName
                        FROM applications
                        INNER JOIN client
                        ON applications.clientId = client.cryptId`

`Table Clients
ID   clientId    FirstName    LastName
0    1duvbj      John         Doe
1    2dhyba      Jane         Doe`

Table Applications
ID   appId     date          approved
0    1duvbj    2017-01-01    '0'
1    2dhyba    Jane          '1'

Comment: Can you add some sample data, index information and time that it takes for execution ?

Comment: always use explain keyword to get info about your query

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I added some sample data. There's 56 columns in the client table, and 41 in the applications table. Should I be adding indexes to all of my columns or just certain one's. I'm not well versed in indexing.

Comment: No, Add index for columns that you want to include in joins, where clauses and sort by. So in your case, that would be for `applications.clientId` and `client.cryptId`.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know your table structure, but in general I assume that you have no index

So my solution would be to create an index on applications.clientId and client.cryptId.

The necessary commands:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_applications_clientid
ON applications (clientId);

CREATE INDEX idx_client_clientid
ON client (cryptId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I added some sample data. There's 56 columns in the client table, and 41 in the applications table. Should I be adding indexes to all of my columns or just certain one's. I'm not well versed in indexing.

Comment: In general its a bad idea to add indexes to all columns, as it will decrease the speed for inserts and updates. Try adding my proposed indexes and check how the speed of your query behaves.